# How do I install Google Chrome beta/dev for all users?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, installation, windows-installer

Google has an MSI installer for Windows meant for installing Chrome for all users, versus just the user account that installs it. As best as I can tell though, this installs the Stable channel.

I would like to have the Dev channel installed for all users. This is mostly because I am comfortable, prefer, and only use the Dev channel, but I do have the guest account enabled on this machine so if someone has to use the machine, I want them to have access to Chrome and not fire up IE.

Even though some sites claim the MSI installer will work for the Dev channel, it does only seem to install Stable (currently 10.0.648.204).

So then, how can I install the Dev channel for all users?

Comment: You didn't end up with the dev version - that's currently at 11.0.696.16 (although I expect it to go to 12 soon, as the beta channel just got version 11 today)

Comment: That's my point - how can the dev channel be installed for all users? Some have mistakenly claimed the MSI installer does this, but from my experience it does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### New Info

Well, since the Google Pack [is now discontinued](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2011/09/fall-spring-clean.html), people will need a new way to deploy Chrome for all users on a system.  Thankfully, Google Chrome's [Alternate Installer](https://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=126299) allows you to do just that.  In fact, if one pays careful attention to the URL parameters, all kinds of interesting options present themselves...  One can download any of the Stable, Beta, or Dev channels for one user or all users, online or offline installers.  For the OP, [this link](http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?extra=devchannel&platform=win&system=true) will download the online installer for the Dev Channel for all users.

### Old Info

Another option for getting Chrome available for all users is to install it via the Google Pack -- it uses Google's Updater mechanism rather than the MSI.  It may also be required for the following instructions to work, as I'm not sure that the MSI installs Google Updater.

That said, once you have Chrome installed for all users, follow the instructions in [Comment #1 on Chromium Bug #33682](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=33682#c1):

> Change the value of the `ap` string in Google Chrome's subkey under
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Google\Update\ClientState` or
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Google\Update\ClientState` to `1.1-beta` or
>   `2.0-dev`.

After this is done, the next time Chrome updates, it will update to the selected channel.

Also of note: The bug is marked as WontFix.  Google does not plan to allow for deploying the Beta or Dev channels by default.

Comment: Mmm... Pehaps it can solve my problem... http://superuser.com/questions/266581/google-chrome-does-not-launch-after-some-months-without-using-it-in-windows-xp-se

Comment: I wish that this answer had included an explanation of exactly **how** the Google Pack solution works to get Chrome installed for multiple users. It's certainly not obvious.

Comment: oh wait; never mind; it seems to just happen as an intrinsic side effect of that installation mechanism.

Comment: I used this after installing the Enterprise MSI, although I had to create the key since it didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

[Google Chrome Portable](http://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable) can get the job done. You can download the Beta and Dev versions, too.

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I don't see the relevance of installing the portable version to address the issue of installing beta/dev for all users.

Comment: Well, each user could install the portable version, or you can share a single installation as it is self-contained in a folder. I admit it would be a workaround, and not a true solution.

Comment: I see, true that would be a workaround. Thanks!