# Google Chrome does not launch after some months without using it in Windows XP/Seven

Tags: google-chrome

Well, I have in computers I use with Windows XP or Seven more than one browser installed on them, generally Internet Explorer 8, Firefox 4, Opera 11 and Google Chrome.

I often use Firefox, but I want to use Google Chrome sometimes because I have a lot of addons and webapps on it.

The issue is: when I try to execute Chrome after some months without using it, it does not function. Using Proccess Explorer or Task Manager, I can see that there is not any Google proccesses running. Then I reinstall it and all functions. But if I do not use it for some months again, it will not function...

Is it an update problem? Must I use Chrome everyday or is there another way to avoid that issue?

PS: I installed English and Portuguese last versions (how to get the version numbers when it does not execute?), not at the same time, and it continues to do not launch...

PS2: There is a running Google Update proccess that is launched in startup:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   Name:            Google Update
   Type:            REG_SZ
   Data:            "C:\Users\Ubirajara\AppData\Local\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe" /c

Comment: Probably - if a reinstall solves the problem. You could just open up Chrome once a week to let it auto-update.

Comment: Well, I think the cause would be it, but I'm not sure. I googled it but did not found anything about. I can test using Chrome one a week :) but I would like to know the cause and the best solution. ChrisF, do you know a way to program Chrome autoupdate (settings/command line for batch or shortcut/scheduling in Windows)?

Comment: Sorry, no. There is the Google Updater tool - do you have that running?

Comment: Using Autoruns I can see some Google application that is launched with Windows startup... Later when I arrive home I can write its name.

Comment: *I can see a Google application

Comment: see PS2 (added in the bottom of issue description)...

Comment: It's not the best answer - I'm waiting for a better one - but I gave up installing Chrome on my computer and I am using a portable Chrome through LiberKey (http://www.liberkey.com/).

Comment: <I>"I'm miffed & angry with you. You're cheating with me...That's why I'm not working. :D :P ;)" --- Your beloved Chrome</I>. On a serious note, It seems to be a bug with your system. I don't see Google incorporating any such futile functionality or leaving such a bug in their product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not deselected the options to back up your data -- on by default when you sign into Chrome with your Google account -- you can (uninstall and) reinstall Chrome. Your synced settings will be restored when you log in to the fresh Chrome.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you already tried that. This seems like the simplest route -- Chrome is built to be refreshed from a server, and will even install to a non system location by default, allowing it to be a transient, up-to-date application with data "in the cloud." I can't think of one reason why you would need to run the outdated version.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running a third-party software firewalls of any kind? If so, are they configured to silently block executables that have changed (i.e. due to upgrade)?

Comment: Surely these would either complain or block the reinstalled Chrome too.

Answer (score 0):

It might be Chrome has some security feature that prevents it from starting if it's too out-dated. That would sorta make sense, because badly outdated browser is a big security risk. However, it should autoupdate itself, not just refuse to start....