# Enable Chrome Extensions for all users

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

How can I have the **same** [Extentions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions) for **all** the users of the same computer?

More details:

- I only want this for Windows, but if your solution works for others, that's ok.
- When I say *users* I mean: Chrome users, not Windows users.
- And not having to install every extension for every user.
- And a better solution would be that the user data (for the extension) doesn't get shared between users.
- Would be nice, if this is just a setting/configuration from Chrome, and not Windows.

Is this possible ? how ?

Comment: Why You put link to the Apps, not (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/category/extensions)

Comment: There is process to install chrome extension manually with .crx file just by drag & drop.

Answer (score 2):

The only workaround is to use the same Chrome profile.

Think Yourself - if it possible at all if Extensions are stored in Chrome users profiles[see: Where are the Extensions Files stored?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/6EVtjeaWObs/discussion%5B1-25%5D), and Software (Chrome) is stored in Windows users profiles.

Maybe other way described here - write script to install Chrome with all extensions: [Google Chrome's Alternate Installer](https://superuser.com/questions/261141/how-do-i-install-google-chrome-beta-dev-for-all-users)