# Install and enable extension for all Windows users in Chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, flash-player

Similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/774543/enable-chrome-extensions-for-all-users), except that I'm wanting a solution for all *Windows* users.

We have an NT4-style domain hosted by Samba, so we cannot use Group Policy to deploy the setting, as recommended by Google's Dev Forum.

The issue is that with the latest update, Flash videos do not automatically play in Google Chrome. Our users are complaining about it, and I can't seem to find a way to do it without touching every computer, with every user logged in. It appears to be a preference, not a setting - meaning that each user chooses what to enable and not.

Flash is up to date as of yesterday on the systems. The current fix is for each user having the issue to go to **about:plugins**, and manually enable Adobe Flash Player to launch. I am looking for a solution that does this for all Windows users logging in to each of the computers.