# How do I deploy Edge/Chrome extensions for all users on the same computer?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, microsoft-edge, deployment

When I say "all users", I mean Windows users, not Chrome users.
Just like when you install an application, you choose "Install for everyone on this computer" instead of "Install for me only".

I would like to:

1. Deploy a batch of Edge or Chrome **extensions** for computers in Active Directory, available to all users on the computer (This may be done via the last link) .
2. Keep only one copy of the **program part** of the extension on the computer, instead of copying it to each user's directory one by one. This can reduce the storage space occupied.
3. On the basis of 2, allow the extension to have its own configuration for different users, instead of using the same Chrome profile.
4. If possible, provide a way to unify the common parts inside the configuration file of an extension.

(I found the following content in su, but not the same as my needs. [Enable Chrome Extensions for all users](https://superuser.com/questions/774543/enable-chrome-extensions-for-all-users))

(I found the following in ms, but it still looks like a separate installation for each user. https://docs.microsoft.com/zh-cn/deployedge/microsoft-edge-manage-extensions-policies#force-install-an-extension )

Is it possible and how to do? Thanks for any replies! (Sorry for my bad English)

Comment: You can do this via GPO. Get the Chrome ADMX (administrative templates) and in there you will find the option to forcefully install extensions.

Comment: Can a forcefully installation be "one copy only"?

Comment: I don't know if Chrome or Edge allows this. As far as i know, extensions live exclusively in user directories, so i cant help you beyond this.